# Get the element availability status in boolean using protractor

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, node.js, protractor

I am trying to get the element present status of the using 'If' condition but unfortunately i am not able to get the result as either 'true' or 'false' instead i am getting like(when element is available i am getting result as 'true' and when the element is not available i am getting error message like below)

> - Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .alert-message.ng-binding.alert.alert-success)

Below is the code i used

```
describe("test 1", function () {
    it("testing", function () {
        var userCreationSuccessConfirmationMsg = element(by.className('alert-message ng-binding alert alert-success'));
        var userCreationFailureConfirmationMsg = element(by.className('alert-message ng-binding alert alert-danger'));

        browser.driver.get(testData.UBETURL);
        login.loginToUbet('sysadmin', 'password');
        console.log('Somesh');
        element(by.linkText('Configuration')).click();
        element(by.linkText('Create New User')).click();
        element.all(by.id('saveUser')).first().click();
        console.log(expect(userCreationSuccessConfirmationMsg.isDisplayed()));
        userCreationSuccessConfirmationMsg.isDisplayed().then(function (status) {
            if (status) {
                console.log(status);
            } else {
                console.lgo(status);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

How to get the element availability status in Boolean using if, please guide me here???

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isPresent` to determine whether an element is present or not in the page:

```
userCreationSuccessConfirmationMsg.isPresent().then(function (status) {
    if (status) {
        console.log('present');
    } else {
        console.log('not present');
    }
});
```

The doc:

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isPresent

Comment: how long the isPresent() would be wait for or what is the maximum time this will wait for the element to be present. To be more precise on my question, there is an element in web page which will be displayed only after 30 sec from the page launched time, here your above code would work?

Comment: The method `isPresent` doesn't wait. Use `browser.wait` to wait for a condition.

Comment: is the below code would wait for the element to be present?
'browser.wait(userCreationSuccessConfirmationMsg.isPresent().then(function (status) {
    if (status) {
        console.log('present');
    } else {
        console.log('not present');
    }
}),5000);'

Answer (score 0):

If you know that success is when (and only when) the returned status is 'true', then you can just check the exact text to be that string:

```
userCreationSuccessConfirmationMsg.isDisplayed().then(function (status) {
    if (status === 'true') {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: do you mean that isDisplayed() would return a text instead of boolean response?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i believe you don't actually need logging when all passing smoothly:

```
expect(userCreationSuccessConfirmationMsg.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy('Your message that should be printed when expectation is failed.')
```

Jasmine can accept optional message for expectations, almost all matchers support it.

Also you can look at my library - it does matching that element visible in smart way - will wait for element, before fail expectation. Useful when your elements appear with delays. Feature requests are welcome.

https://github.com/Xotabu4/jasmine-protractor-matchers